# When in View Controller lifecycle to present UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller

I would like to present a `UIImagePickerController` immediately when a user tabs on the camera tab in my app to take a photo (similar to many photo taking apps like Instagram, etc). Currently, I have a VC called `CameraViewController` that displays the picture taken from the UIImagePickerController, and in the `viewWillAppear` function of `CameraViewController` I present the `ImagePickerController` **modally** when I detect that no picture have been taken.

While this worked most of the time, I noticed that at times I would get an exception saying:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller ."

Per the suggestion of some SO questions here, I also tried presenting the controller in `viewDidAppear`. However, with `viewDidAppear`, the modal ImagePicker is never dismissed, and I keep getting the error "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ."

**My questions are:**

1. I am currently presenting the ImagePickerController modally for the user to take a picture, and then dismissing it once the picture is taken. Is this generally the way things are done with ImagePickerControllers that are the most reliable/problem-free.
2. Where else should I consider putting the ImagePickerController in the view life cycle to get this desired effect?

Here is my code:

in `viewWillAppear`

```
BOOL modalPresent = (BOOL)(self.presentedViewController);
if (!appDelegate.imageStorageDictionary[@"picture1"]){
    if (modalPresent == NO){
        [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

in `imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

```
//Other lines omitted 
if (![[self imagePickerController] isBeingDismissed]) 
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not getting much about your question regarding `-viewWillAppear` , but one thing you  must know that `-viewWillAppear` would be called more than one time(s). reason being , the first call will be when your `viewController` is loaded and `viewDidLoad` and appear would be called as usual, secondly when you have presented a`modalViewController (imagePickerController)` and when it is dismissed  again `viewWillAppear` will be called because the viewController's view is about to appear..

Secondly regarding you want present camera's functionality when user taps on camera button , do this:

```
  if([UIImagePickerControllerisSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
     if(myPicker)
     {
        [myPicker release];
         myPicker = nil;
      }
 myPicker   = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

     [self presentViewController:myPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *altnot=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Camera Not Available" message:@"Camera Not Available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    altnot.tag=103;
    [altnot show];
    [altnot release];
}
```

for picking already captured images..

-(void)ChooseAlreadyCapturedPhoto
{

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
{
    if(myPicker)
    {
       [myPicker release];
       myPicker = nil;
    }
    myPicker          = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    myPicker.delegate = self;
    myPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    myPicker.allowsEditing = NO;

}
[self presentViewController:myPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

Note: I have released previously allocated object of picker every time when I am using it, but it is not necessary. You can use the only single instance of my picker, don't mark it wrong. And using `imagePicker-controller` inside `viewController` is absolutely fine, it won't harm.. If you present and dismiss modalViewController a no. times, then viewWill appear also would be called , each time you dismiss it.